# Break from within a oneliner

Tags: coffeescript

Is it possible to simplify the second line keeping the code in three lines at the same time? `current` should have the "error" value.

```
for item in [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
  break if (current = if item? then item else "error") is "error"
console.dir current
```

I was trying to make something like that with no luck:

```
for item in [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6]
  current = if item? then item else "error", break
console.dir current
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with a simple statement of the problem your loop is trying to solve rather than trying to force the loop to be a compact opaque mess: fewer lines does not mean better code, quite often it is the opposite. Are you really trying to say `'error'` if anything in the loop is `null` or `undefined` and otherwise grab the last element of the array?

Comment: No, `'error'` is just to put something as an example. Original case is more complex and not even dealing with the array in a straight form. You're right about fewer lines and better code but on the other hand, nothing prohibits me from seeking an elegant fewer lines that would do the code better as long as I have the time to seek for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one liner, that's the best way I found to write it in coffee, but wouldn't in production, so my colleagues won't kill me while reading it.

```
break for item in [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6] when (current = item ? 'error') is 'error'
console.dir current
```

There are actually many way to write this, with exactly the same output in Javascript.

Regards,

Comment: That's an interesting one. Thank you.